# Как снавигировать с ViewPager2 в другой фрагмент (JetpackNavigation)?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-sdk

У меня сингл активити, в нем fragmentHome содержит viewpager2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во fragmentHome находится FragmentFirst.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку должно снавигировать во FragmentSecond (его нету в Viewpager2), тоесть там нету совсем viewpager2. У меня бросает ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.mymessangerfcm:id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment is unknown to this NavController`

А теперь внимание вопрос: почему это происходит и как решить проблему?

[ссылка на англоязычную версию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733945/navigate-from-viewpager2-to-another-fragment-using-jetpack)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовань navController только для навигации внутри одного NavFragment. Т.е. для вашего кейса вы должны иметь примерно такой флоу. 
Есть активити в ней NavController в котором живет и ваш FirstFragment который является хостом для  ViewPager и SecondFragment. Тогда вы можете из ViewPager отдавать событие в FirstFragment и оттуда вызывать SecondFragment.

Из того, что я увидел в вашем коде, у вас вероятно SecondFragment и фрагменты ViewPager-а находятся в разных NavController

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем надо глобал навигейшн использовать : You should use the Global Action. When you are inside the viewpager, actually you are in a different navigation. So, you should make your action as Global. You can check the Global Action from official website :

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

After the making action as global, you can navigate like this;

findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
Note: If you don't see global action after the doing it, rebuild your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733945/navigate-from-viewpager2-to-another-fragment-using-jetpack/60754904#60754904